# Hadwiger's conjecture graph without $K_{4}$ minor has degree $2$

Tags: graph-theory

I'm stuck with the question that asks to prove how I can show by induction based on Hadwiger's conjecture that a graph without a $K_{4}$ minor is at most two connected.

I know that a graph without a $K_{4}$ minor is $3-\text{colorable}$ but how can I prove the degree $2?$

Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Comment: Can we assume that only simple graphs are considered?

Comment: In fact that would be an argument _for_ only allowing simple graphs -- the graph consisting of two vertices connected by 3 edges has minimum degree 3 but no $K_4$ minor.

Comment: Yes sure you are right, only simple graphs are allowed

Comment: Okay, I will answer the question soon then.

Comment: great, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We proceed by structural induction. It is clear that no graph with 4 or fewer vertices which contains no $K_4$ minor can be 3-connected.

Further assume we now have a graph $G = (V, E)$ with no $K_4$ minor which is at most 2-connected.

Now let us define a new graph $G'$ obtained from $G$ by adding a new vertex $v'$ and connecting it to the vertices in some set $X \subseteq V$ such that $G'$ also does not contain a $K_4$ minor.

We assume towards a contradiction that $G'$ is 3-connected.
By Menger's theorem we find that $G$ must have already been 2-connected as adding $v'$ cannot add more than one additional path (disjoint from existing ones in $G$) between any two vertices.
As $G$ was 2-connected, we also get the existence of two vertices $v$ and $w$ such that any triple of disjoint $v$-$w$-paths in $G'$ must include a path containing $v'$ and since we required $G$ to be simple, one of the two $v$-$w$-paths in $G$ must contain some other vertex $x$, giving us the following situation:
[image]
By Menger's theorem, we again obtain 3 disjoint paths between $x$ and $v'$ in $G'$ and thus at least one such path containing neither $v$ nor $w$.
Contracting all these considered paths between the vertices in $\{v, w, x, v'\}$ yields a $K_4$ minor in $G'$.

Note that this proof does not use Hadwiger's conjecture and I see no reason for why it should be used.
Indeed I found other proofs of this fact not using it either, see e.g. Theorem 2.2 in these [lecture notes](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/snorin/math599w2017/Notes.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much! Very well explained

Comment: It think there are some gaps in this proof. The vertices $v$ and $w$ have to be chosen carefully, since two vertices in a 2-connected graph that is not 3-connected can have 3 disjoint paths between them. This is an issue because, for example, your proof relies on the two vertices with exactly two paths between them being in different colour classes. I may have missed something, but I also don't see why one of the paths must contain some $x$ in $V_3$, since in general it should be possible for $v$ and $w$ to lie on a cycle that lies entirely in $V_1\cup V_2$.

Comment: I think you are right. I will try to repair it once I am fully awake.

Comment: I do not want to type all of my findings into comments, so I created a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113721/on-hadwigers-conjecture-graph-without-k4-minor-has-degree-2) for this, if you care.

Comment: I edited the answer according to my findings documented in the chat room linked in the previous comment.

Comment: I have one additional question. Am I right that there has to be a direct path from x to v' and we get the $K_{4}$ minor? But then our graph G' is 4- connected or?

Comment: What do you mean by direct path? To get a 4-connected graph, you need at least 4 disjoint paths between any two vertices. With the way we choose $v$ and $w$, there are at most 3 such paths between the two of them after adding $v'$.